# Search for cascading element using watin

Tags: c#, watin

Please tell me the way to search a cascading element in a page.

For example, there are 10 anchor element tags used in a page. I can simply reach an element using FindBy method i.e. Element.FindBy(). But what to do when i have a cascading element on a page css like ".lineItem .title a"

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure what you mean by saying "cascading element". Are you looking for `<a/>` element contained in element with `class="lineItem"` which is contained in element with `class="title"`? If so, there is at least two things you could do, to find that element:

1. Use `Find.ByExistenceOfRelatedElement<T>(ElementSelector<T> selector)`

   ```
   ie.Link(
       Find.ByExistenceOfRelatedElement<Element>(link => link.Ancestor(
           Find.ByClass("title")
           && Find.ByExistenceOfRelatedElement<Element>(linksAncestor => linksAncestor.Ancestor(
               Find.ByClass("lineItem"))))));
   ```
2. Use `Predicate<Link>`

   ```
   ie.Link(link =>
   {
       var ancestor = link.Ancestor(Find.ByClass("title"));
       return ancestor != null && ancestor.Ancestor(Find.ByClass("lineItem")) != null;
   });
   ```

I bet there is another way.